# Which is cleaner: a constructor with many parameters or many setters after construction?

Tags: php, comparative-review, php5

I'm trying to work out which is cleaner, having a large constructor or having to use many setters on a new object before doing some work with it.

Large constructor:

```
<?php
class PathGeneratorWithBigConstructor {
  //...

  public function __construct($base_directories, $paths, $filename) {
    $this->base_directories = $base_directories;
    $this->paths = $paths;
    $this->filename = $filename;
  }

  //...
}

// Must pass the parameters in the correct order
$path_generator = new PathGeneratorWithBigConstructor($base_directories, $paths, $filename);
```

Many setters:

```
<?php
class PathGeneratorWithSetters {
  //...

  public function set_base_directories($base_directories) {
    $this->base_directories = $base_directories;
  }

  public function set_paths($paths) {
    $this->paths = $paths;
  }

  public function set_filename($filename) {
    $this->filename = $filename;
  }

  //...
}

$path_generator = new PathGeneratorWithSetters;

// These can go in any order
$path_generator->set_paths($paths);
$path_generator->set_filename($filename);
$path_generator->set_base_directories($base_directories);
```

I'm trying to follow Robert "Uncle Bob" Martin's advice in Clean Code where he recommends against having too many parameters in a method. He states on page 40:

> ### Function Arguments
>
> The ideal number of arguments for a function is
>   zero (niladic). Next comes one (monadic), followed
>   closely by two (dyadic). Three arguments (triadic)
>   should be avoided where possible. More than three
>   (polyadic) requires very special justification—and
>   then shouldn’t be used anyway.
>
> Arguments are hard. They take a lot of conceptual
>   power. …

Obviously, I can't quote the whole section here, and if you disagree with his opinion, I'd advise familiarising yourself with the rest of his argument before posting a reply. He goes into greater detail over the next 3-4 pages which I can't summarise here because he has already written the appropriate amount of text on the subject. I do reference his ideas in the following paragraphs which is again why I recommend being familiar with his full opinion before replying.

In the class with the constructor, it's not obvious what order the parameters should go in (no natural ordering - page 42). You can't give a hint to the programmer with the method's name because it's the constructor, which should succinctly describe the object, not the order of its construction parameters (encode the names of the arguments into the function name - page 43).

With the constructor, an error will occur when the object is created if there are too few parameters. With the setters, an error will still occur later if each property is not set correctly, which is also the case for the constructor, so no clear advantage either way. Some IDEs will warn the programmer if the method signature doesn't match, while they can't warn about missing setters.

The parameters in this case can't be combined into an sensible object, because PathGenerator *is* the sensible object! `$base_directories`, `$paths` & `$filename` don't have a logical grouping (reduce the number of arguments by creating objects out of them - page 43).

The class with the setters seems like a lot of work. It also seems too easy to miss one of the setters before trying to get it to do some work. However, reading the code that uses the setter class, it's obvious what it does, much more so than the large constructor version!

The third option, passing in a `$parameters` object/array, as I've seen recommended elsewhere, seems to combine the worst of both styles: extra work is needed to construct the object and it's easy to miss a parameter.

My goal is that the code should be easy to maintain (therefore also easy to understand) and easy to use. Which of the two styles is cleaner?

Comment: You haven't stated what the task that this code is intended to accomplish. (See [ask].) What is the `PathGenerator` class for? Is it intended to be mutable or immutable? What will you end up doing with the instance variables? Furthermore, based on the title of the question, it appears that you might be asking about a general best practice, with this skeleton code serving purely as a hypothetical example. Generic best-practice discussions would be off-topic for Code Review, as per the [help/on-topic].

Comment: If you wish to ask for a review of your `PathGenerator` class, please edit the question to include more code, and to clarify the requirements and intended usage.

Comment: I'm investigating if this question would be welcome on Software Engineering

Answer (score 2):

Where do you want to validate the parameters?

- If the parameters are passed inside the constructor (either as multiple parameters or as a structure), the constructor can check all of them and throw an exception if something is missing/off. That way, the other methods of the class can assume they are valid.
- If the parameters are passed using setters, then every method needs to check if all the required values are present and valid. If the code runs in a multithreaded context, then there's additional protections needed as a value can change unexpectedly inside a method call if a setter is called from a different thread.

Comment: If they are validated as they are set, there's not much difference between each style. If they are validated before being used, there's no difference between the styles. PHP is not threadsafe anyway, including the "threadsafe" version.

Answer (score 1):

Something that I do when I have too many arguments in a constructor is to figure out what attributes are going to be the most important and set defaults for the rest. They can be modified later if needed. This allows the client to use the class with intuitive defaults and later modify them in order to fit their use case.

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about this since I posted the question. It seems to me that there's a difference between mutable properties and immutable properties.

```
class PoweredVehicle {
  protected $odometer = 0;

  protected $vehicle_type;
  protected $colour;

  public function __construct($vehicle_type, $colour) {
    $this->vehicle_type = $vehicle_type;
    $this->colour = $colour;
  }

  //...
}

$my_car = new PoweredVehicle(new PoweredVehicleType($make, $model), $colour);
$my_car->set_driver($me);
$my_car->adjust_mirrors($me->driving_mirror_preference);
$my_car->fasten_seatbelt($me);
$my_car->drive();
```

The odometer of a new car should always be zero, and there shouldn't be a way to change it from outside the object. It should not be passed in as a parameter, nor should there be any methods that can change it directly. The `drive` method should increase it.

My car's make, model and colour are immutable under normal circumstances. I certainly don't have the option to just decide that any of them are going to be different. It therefore makes sense that these properties are passed to the constructor and set as read-only properties. The make and model are related to each other, so it makes sense to have a `PoweredVehicleType` object with at least both of those properties.

However, the driver, mirror preference and whether the driver's seat belt is fastened or not can all change very easily. My car shouldn't `drive` without a driver, but I don't want to construct a new car each time with the driver already set. I want the ability to stop the car, change drivers and `drive` it again.

So, this is the way I'll be constructing my objects, unless I'm persuaded there's a better way.

Comment: None of those properties are immutable https://3v4l.org/VIlXL

Comment: @arcanine Where is that documented? I haven't been able to find it in the PHP 7 docs. I would also hope no-one ever uses that in production code!

Comment: If you want Closure, have another look in the documentation!

Answer (score 0):

Any parameters that are required for the class to function should be passed into the constructor. That's what it's for. If you're still constructing the class by setting things after the constructor is called then you're not using the constructor properly.

Sending a buttload of arguments is a crappy idea too. If you have a class that needs lots of data to construct, consider using an array.

```
class Person(){

    private $favoriteColor;
    private $lengthOfLegHair;
    private $numberOfUnderpants;

    public function __constructor(array $args){
        foreach($args as $key=>$val)
            $this->$key = $val;
    }

}

$ted = new Person(array(
    "favoriteColor" => "green",
    "lengthOfLegHair" => "7 inches",
    "numberOfUnderpants" => 2
));
```

Comment: I can't even begin to explain how much of a bad idea this is. You just erased any form of type hinting validation.

Comment: @Stephan-v - you can't even begin, huh? lol.. well i can't even begin to tell you what a bad idea it is to rely on type hinting to manage your property types. there are other forms of validation.besides type hinting in php is very limited. you can't type hint a string, or primitive values for example, which makes php's type hinting basically useless. but you go ahead and keep exaggerating if it makes you feel like a smart guy..

Comment: `you can't type hint a string, or primitive values for example` Uhm yes you can.

Comment: oh i see. they added that in php7. very nice. but still you don't gotta bust in here like *ermagerhd i can't even begin* it's really not that terrible to use an array. there are other ways of validating your stuff. and type hinting is hardly the best method.

Comment: You are trying to educate people with misguided information. This should be solved through composition and not be simply chucking arrays into a constructor for the sake of diminishing arguments. The aim is to decrease the amount of conceptual power necessary to read and understand code, not increase it.

Comment: tell me @Stephan-v, is `string $color` really more descriptive than `"favoriteColor" => "green"`? no, not so much.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I'd use `string $favoriteColor`.
The issue with passing an array is that you don't know which keys can be used, how to write them (favoriteColor, favouriteColour, favorite_color), what type they should be. You are facing some form of semi black box. It's useful if you already know exactly what each option is and does, but there's no hint telling you how to instantiate the object.
If there are too many arguments, use a Configuration class :
`public function __construct(PersonConfiguration $conf)`.

Comment: Like he aluded to, you can have a separate validator module.
you pass it the array of args. you pass it the expected names (favorite color) , type(string) ,restrictions (0<= x < 10)... and you can even do custom validation functions on a per-property basis. PHP is limited in its validation, and you'll end up needing a more feature-rich validator module for bigger projects anyway. As for knowing which fields you can/can't use, you'd specify that in the constructor, with the valid fields and their specs and pass them into the validator module. It becomes a matter of looking a few lines below.